# Enabling Drag and Drop from TOC to Python Script Tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, drag-and-drop

I am creating an ArcTool and wanting to have my input parameters encompass a drop down menu where files in the TOC can be chosen. The tool is shown below [image: This is the current look of the tool.]

I currently have a .csv and .shp sitting in my TOC and would like to have dropdown menus present on the "Stats File" and "Spatial Data" parameters so that I can choose them easily, instead of browsing to the file through the folder connection.

I am receiving an "Invalid Drop Item" message.

Comment: Is this a Python script tool in a `*.tbx` or a Python Toolbox tool (`*.pyt`)?  Either way I think drag and drop functionality should just work in the same places that it does for any system tools.  I think you should use a test tool to describe a single parameter that you think should but does not appear to be supporting drag and drop.

Comment: @PolyGeo it is a script tool in .tbx. I am receiving an "Invalid Drop Item" message. This also occurs with a test tool.

Comment: Next time you have a question about script tool parameters, please include a screenshot/description of the tool *properties* not just the tool dialog so we can see what data types you have actually set for the input parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a script tool, you need to setup your input types accordingly from Parameters tab of the script `Properties`. For your layer parameter, select `Feature Layer` and your csv input (as in your TOC), select `Table View` from the **Data Type** column.